# Entity Framework Check if Collection Contains Item

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to execute the below query in EF5:

```
var data = from adi in _repo.AccountingDocumentItems
                   from e in adi.Employees
                   let c = adi.Employees.Count()
                   where
                       (adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate >= start && adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate <= queryEnd) &&
                       (c > 0) &&
                       (_repo.AccountingEntries.Count(p => p.AccountingDocumentId == adi.AccountingDocumentId) != 0))
```

The part that is breaking is the last line of the where clause where I attempt to check if an AccountingEntries item exists that is linked to the AccountingDocumentId of the AccountingDocumentItem. I get an error:

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'AppName.Domain.Entities.AccountingEntry'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I'm not understanding why this is occurring as I'm specifically selecting the Count of those items. I've also tried the following with the same result:

```
_repo.AccountingEntries.Any(x => x.AccountingDocumentId == adi.AccountingDocumentId)
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Gary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try

```
var accountingEntriesId = _repo.AccountingEntries.Select(m => m.AccountingDocumentId);

var data = from adi in _repo.AccountingDocumentItems
                   where
                       adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate >= start && 
                       adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate <= queryEnd &&
                       adi.Employees.Any() &&
                       accountingEntriesId.Contains(adi.AccountingDocumentId)
```

**EDIT**

you could also use a `inner join` : if the element doesn't exist in AccountingEntries, nothing will be retrieved, which is (if I'm not wrong) what you want.

```
 var data = from adi in _repo.AccounginDocumentItems
            join ae in _rep.AccountingEntries on adi.AccountingDocumentId equals ae.AccountingDocumentId
            where
                 adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate >= start && 
                 adi.AccountingDocument.DocumentDate <= queryEnd &&
                 adi.Employees.Any()
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks, the above certainly works but performance-wise it's not suitable as my AccountingEntries table could run into the many thousands. I haven't checked this with Profiler, but I assume it would return all AccountingDocumentId fields from the AccountingEntries table.

Comment: @Gary certainly it will... I gave an alternative in Edit.

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks again, a join will certainly work. I was trying to dynamically filter the query based on a Boolean field called 'ReceiptMustExist' which is why I didn't go the join route in the first place, but I can always just run a different query without the join as needed. Thanks.